# How to activate a Applescript Dialog

Tags: applescript

I wrote an Applescript to move one or more selected mail-messages to a selected mailbox in Apple Mail. The target-mailbox must be selected from a "Choose from list"  Dialog.

This list is created in the script, which is started by pressing a (QuickKeys) shortcut key-combination.

This all works fine, except that when the Dialog pops up (as frontmost window), I have to click on it with a mouse to activate it. I cannot activate it with Command-Tab or any other key-combination.

Is there a way to find this existing Dialog in OS-X and activate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    activate
    choose from list {"Item 1", "Item 2"}
end tell
```

To select the first item in the list without the mouse, press Down Arrow.
It seems that the dialog doesn't appear in OS X application switcher.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the correct solution. I wrapped the "choose from list"  lines with your  other three lines and this worked indeed.

Comment: You're welcome. That's right. You wrap `choose from list` in the _System Events_ tell block with the `activate` command. It seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

- Before the `choose from list` line `activate` Mail.app
- Wrap the `choose from list` line in an `tell application "Mail"` block

Comment: I tried to insert "activate" into the script. It does activate the dialog when run from the Script Editor, but unfortunately not when run from the Mail app.

Comment: Just `activate` might be not sufficient, you need to write `activate application "Mail"`, if the line is **not** in an `Mail` tell block. Or try `set frontmost of application "Mail" to true`.